# Proof for getting delta function on $t \to t_0 $ from the equation of the propagator for the free particle in 1 dimension

Tags: path-integral, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator, analyticity

From Sakurai's quantum  mechanics  equation 2.5.16 give propagator for a free particle in 1 dimension.
Equation 2.5.16 is

$$K (x^",t;x',t_0)=\sqrt {m\over {2\pi i\hbar (t-t_0)}} \exp \Biggl [{im (x^"-x')^2 \over 2 \hbar (t-t_0) }\Biggr]\tag{2.5.16}$$

When  $\lim _{t \to t_0} $ propagator $K (x^",t;x',t_0)$ must equal to a dirac delta function.
Sakurai also states this condition in equation 2.5.9

$$\lim_{t \to t_ 0}  K (x^",t;x',t_0) = \delta  (x^"-x') .\tag{2.5.9} $$

Can any one spend some of your precious  little time  to  mathematically show this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that to make mathematical sense of the limit (2.5.9) it is implicitly assumed that $${\rm Re}(i\Delta t)~>~0\tag{1}$$ is slightly positive via the pertinent [Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=i+epsilon+prescription). After [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) via a [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) 
$$\Delta\tau~\equiv~ i\Delta t,\tag{2}$$ 
eq. (2.5.16) is just the [heat kernel representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Semigroups)$^1$ 
$$ \delta(x)~=~ \lim_{|\alpha|\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}} e^{-\alpha x^2}, \qquad {\rm Re}(\alpha)~>~0, \tag{3}$$
of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Here we have identified $$\alpha~\equiv~\frac{m}{2\hbar\Delta\tau}.\tag{4}$$

--

$^1$ To prove the heat kernel representation (3), insert a test function on each side.

Comment: You use $|\alpha |  \to \infty $ this means if $\alpha $ is negative then it goes to $-\infty$ and if $\alpha$ is positive it goes to $\infty$.In  the case  of limit goes to $- \infty$ we get $e^{ positive number }$ this is not a delta function am I right? @Qmechanic

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: If we take the case of only $\alpha $ is positive then we cannot get $\infty$ at $x=0$, Then how can you say we get a delta function?@Qmechanic

Comment: Note that the square root blows up, and if $x=0$ it is not tamed by the exponential.

Comment: how?@ Qmechanic